# Android - Submenu items in BottomBar?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to add a submenu to the Android [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/wiki/Getting-Started), similar to [this](http://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-submenu-example.html) except the submenu should show after clicking a BottomBar icon.

I was able to get the BottomBar working, just looking for a simple submenu example. I basically want the user to click "Color" on the BottomBar and have a list of colors appear. After selecting, an ImageView tint will change based on selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning BottomBar and using a row of plain Buttons with ListViews for pop-up menus. Much more control and better suited for my scenario.